# How to use many variable in array of array for calculating and show (Vue+laravel)

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, vue.js

I have table list of organization and table review of each organization then I want to calculate the average rate of each organization (one of the attributes in review table) This is JSON file that I have

```
{
   id: 17,
   name_org: "AAA company",
   picture: "default.jpg",
   headerpic: "no-preview.png",
   type: "hardware,software,network",
   review: [
    {
       review_id: 3,
       org_id: 17,
       user_id: 2,
       description: "Not bad",
       rating: 5,
    },
    {
       review_id: 4,
       org_id: 17,
       user_id: 2,
       description: "Good",
       rating: 3,
    }
   ]
},
{
    id: 18,
    name_org: "US company",
    picture: "default.jpg",
    headerpic: "no-preview.png",
    type: "hardware,software,network",
    rating: 0,
    review: [
    {
       review_id: 5,
       org_id: 18,
       user_id: 2,
       description: "Well",
       rating: 5,
    }
   ]
}
```

I want to plus every rating in each organization and divide sum of rating with the number of rating (AVG) then show AVG in each organization

```
methods: {
    getOrgData() {
      axios.get("api/listorgs").then(response => {
        this.ListOrgs = response.data;
      });
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      ListOrgs: []
    };
  },
```

Can you tell me about that syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could easily use a for loop here. Here's a method which could do the trick :

```
getAvg(organization) {
  let total = 0;
  for(var i = 0 ; i < organization.review.length; i++) {
    total += organization.review[i].rating;
  }
  let avg = total / organization.review.length;
  return avg;
}
```

With this method, you just have to call it in your template, for example :

```
<div>{{ getAvg(organization) }}</div>
```

Here's a fiddle I created to solve your problem : [Get rating average](https://jsfiddle.net/yarjqh8L/3/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem, glad I helped.

Answer (score 1):

let us say that array of objects(company) is on `companies` variable.

```js
companies = [
    {
        id: 17,
        name_org: "AAA company",
        picture: "default.jpg",
        headerpic: "no-preview.png",
        type: "hardware,software,network",
        review: [
            {
                review_id: 3,
                org_id: 17,
                user_id: 2,
                description: "Not bad",
                rating: 5,
            },
            {
                review_id: 4,
                org_id: 17,
                user_id: 2,
                description: "Good",
                rating: 3,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 18,
        name_org: "US company",
        picture: "default.jpg",
        headerpic: "no-preview.png",
        type: "hardware,software,network",
        rating: 0,
        review: [
            {
                review_id: 5,
                org_id: 18,
                user_id: 2,
                description: "Well",
                rating: 5,
            }
        ]
    }
];

companies.forEach(function(company, key){
    var divideHere = 0;
    var totalRev = 0;
    company.review.forEach(function(rev, key2){
        divideHere += 1;
        totalRev += rev.rating;
    })
    var thisCompanyAveRating = totalRev / divideHere;
    companies[key].rating = thisCompanyAveRating;

    console.log(companies[key].name_org + ': ' + companies[key].rating);
})
```